# Multiple Excepts Per Post with Categories for Excerpts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I am looking for a solution that would allow there to be multiple excerpt boxes per post in a custom post type, and for there to be a way to have those excerpts have categories.  I know I can add meta boxes to give extra text areas and display that text, but I'm not quite sure that's what I'm looking for.

To clarify, I have a custom post type for testimonials.  That post type has categories which are displayed on pages based on which category is checked.  Some of the testimonials will have more than one quote in them that I want to use, so rather than have multiple posts for the the same full testimonial I want to have several excerpt boxes on the same post.  I hope this makes sense, its a bit difficult to describe I guess.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes, custom meta boxes is what you should be looking for. It can be done programmatically, but using a good plugin will help solve this issue (and many others) quite fast.

Using [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) it would go like this:

## Setting the Custom Field

[image: setting custom field]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

**Note the *Repeatable* option.**

In the same screen, there's also this:

[image: setting the post type]

*I created the "Testimonials" CPT with the very plugin, but all registered CPTs (by theme or plugins) should already appear here.*

## Resulting Meta Box in the CPT Page

[image: resulting meta box in cpt page]

## Alternative

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) is another great plugin, but the repeatable option is a premium add-on.

Comment: I ended up using a repeatable meta box text area built with the Easy Custom Content Types plugin, which is essentially the same method you just provided.  I had forgotten all about this thread, it was several months back.  Thanks for your answer though, I'll check it solved from you.