# How to Add Table Rearranging to WordPress Backend?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to make a wordpress theme that has a feature where you can add/remove/rearrange rows in a table.  Ideally I would want it to be a drag and drop action.  The output needs to simply be a table with several header rows, followed by content rows.  This is for an actor's website, so it would be for a resume page.  So FILM>credits  THEATRE>credits

This is what the end product should look like:

[image]

Pretty much I'm just trying to make it as easy as possible for a user to change his/her resume.  Right now I'm using 
add-row-below" buttons in the tinyMCE, but that can get kind of confusion for non tech people.

Ideally I would be able to add this to a certain page inside of wordpress, but putting it in a settings tab for the theme would work as well.  Any thoughts, ideas, answers would be most appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

For an end user, I'd suggest a Custom Fields plugin solution like in this [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13400461/1287812) <sup><sub>(using [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) or [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/))</sub></sup>.

Programmatically, a Repeatable Field is the way to go.

This helper library may be of interest, [Admin Page Class](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/my-options-panel):

> Works with plugins as well as themes
>   Easily brand-able (via hooks).
>   Import Export features.
>   Available fields are:
>   [...]
>   Sortable Drag & Drop
>   Repeater Field which can be set as sortable
>   OOP Code all the way (which means easy to extend and modify).

A Gist example of Meta Box with a [Sortable Repeatable Field](https://gist.github.com/2057532) <sup><sub>[--fork](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/44f7dbf4b8b0d1eaf25c)</sub></sup>
[image: meta box with sortable repeatable field]

And a full example here at SO: [Adding custom image fields and other fields at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452453/1287812).