# Dynamic single page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, singlepage

I have a single page in wordpress but it has 3 slides of text using orbit slider.Orbit slider works like this (one slide) :

```
 <li>
<div class="small-12 large-6 columns text">
<h1>Scelerisque urna!</h1>
<img class="line" src="img/small-line.png">
<p>Urna turpis dictumst porttitor amet scelerisque</p>

<p>Phasellus nec ultricies risus</p>
</div>
<div class="small-12 large-6 columns"><img src="img/car.jpg"></div>
 </li>
```

so one slide is in one `<li></li>` . How can i make a new post, then in there have a option like "Add new slide" so a new text editor appears or something where the user can put an image and text for the second slide and if he wants add a new slide ?

**one slide :**
http://pokit.org/get/?666cf2d698a981e7cb0605fa7c2ca782.jpg

**second slide :**
http://pokit.org/get/?591d6f998229d24f1442ae0b635a0797.jpg

I forgot to say I want an option to add unlimited slides not only three

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can be done with this plugin ?

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-anything-slider/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

Three ways of doing this:

1. Use the post/page attachments as slides. Relevant WordPress function: [`get_children()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children). Pass the post/page ID and retrieve all image attachments. Loop through them and build your output.
2. Use a custom meta box with repeatable uploading fields. Solution here in SO: [Adding custom image fields and other fields at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14445904/1287812) . Relevant function: [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). Get the meta data and loop.
3. Use a plugin to add repeatable uploading fields. Solution at [WordPress Answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75663/12615). Get the meta data with the plugin custom functions or with `get_post_meta` and loop.