# PHP Multidimensional array within nested foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Working on a wordpress metabox-plugin and trying to save metadata as a multidimensional array (in text that i explode later on).

This is my code:

```
function wordpress_metabox() {

 $event_adress = explode('|', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_event_adress', true));
 foreach ($event_id as $key => $id){

  echo '<div class="event">
  <div class="ticket">
  <input type="text" name="_event_adress[]" value="'.$event_adress[$key].'" />
   <input type="text" name="_event_price[]" value="'.$event_price[$key].'" />
  </div><!-- end .ticket -->
  <div class="ticket">
   <input type="text" name="_event_adress[]" value="'.$event_adress[$key].'" />
   <input type="text" name="_event_price[]" value="'.$event_price[$key].'" />
  </div><!-- end .ticket -->
  <input type="button" class="button" id="add_ticket" value="+ Add ticket" />
 </div><!-- end .event -->
 <input type="button" class="button" id="add_event" value="+ Add Event" />';

 }

}

//this is the save function
function wordpress_metabox_save($post_id, $post) {

 // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
 if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
     return $post->ID;

 // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
 // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

 $event_meta['_event_adress'] = $_POST['_event_adress'];
 $event_meta['_event_id'] = $_POST['_event_id'];

 // Add values of $event_meta as custom fields
 foreach ($event_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $event_meta array!
     if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
     $value = implode('|', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, separate with |

     if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
         update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
     } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
        add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
     }
     if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
 }
}
```

The  should actually be a foreach-loop but i haven't gotten that far yet that's why i wrote the same div twice to illustrate. Can someone please answer how i can save each ticket adress and price in a multidimensional array? I'm not sure if it's possible to type e.g. _event_adress[][] to store each data within a nested array? Or do i have to type the first key in?

Comment: Well for your information `update_post_meta` can save array as serialize value. You don't need to save each post meta value.

Comment: I would also avoid using implode/explode. As Rahil said, you should be able to serialize these automatically which is much better practice than joining with | or any other symbol for that matter.

Comment: @RahilWazir great i will consider that in the future. As you see i'm currently joining the values with the |-symbol which works fine for now. However, the big question is how i can separate the ticket data so that each ticket is stored like this:
$array[KEY_FOR_EVENT][KEY_FOR_TICKET]

any clues?

Comment: WordPress has tons of helpful functions. Like, [Maybe Serialize?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize) and then you can use something like, [Maybe Unserialize?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_unserialize) which are both funny function names that i love so Maybe they're helpful?

Comment: The arrays `$event_id` and `$event_price` are coming from **nowhere**... Please, check the guide [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). . . .  I also think there's *no point* in imploding/exploding, and if 1, 2, 3... users are insisting about that, well... maybe you should listen. Here's a [full working meta box plugin with repeatable fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14452453/1287812), that I think may help you.