# Wordpress: Calling custom Image Field in page

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I found this great thread on how to add multiple custom image fields in a post:

[Adding custom image fields and other fields at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445904/adding-custom-image-fields-and-other-fields-at-the-same-time)

On the admin side, it works perfectly. Using this function will probably automatically show the added images in your post in a standard theme-setup. However, I am calling my posts directly, using this:

```
<?php
        $post_id = 222;
        $queried_post = get_post($post_id);
        $content = $queried_post->post_content;
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
?>
<h2><?php echo $queried_post->post_title; ?></h2>
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

And after that I want to manually add all the images I put in the custom field.... But I can't figure how these images are stored and how I call them. It's probably quite simple but I am missing the knowledge to know about all the Wordpress commands...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I got it working, but it's not very pretty. [Mevius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3518452/rnevius) showed me how to use `get_post_meta` to put my values in an array (thx for that), but this produces an array in array in an array. To get the image's urls I now use this:

```
<?php 
    $queried_imagemeta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );
    foreach ($queried_imagemeta as $imagearray) {
        foreach ($imagearray as $imageurl) {
            foreach ($imageurl as $singleimage)  { ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $singleimage; ?>" class="customfield-image"/>
            <?php } 
        }

    } ?>
```

Which works, but looks awful. By the way, this is how the array is built in functions.php:

```
$gallery_data = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count( $_POST['gallery']['image_url'] ); $i++ ) 
    {
        if ( '' != $_POST['gallery']['image_url'][ $i ] ) 
        {
            $gallery_data['image_url'][]  = $_POST['gallery']['image_url'][ $i ];
            $gallery_data['image_desc'][] = $_POST['gallery']['image_desc'][ $i ];
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to simplify this? Thx!

Comment: `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );` means you can access the same meta with `get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );`

Comment: Thx for the quick comment! However, adding that that line doesn't really do anything :(
I know tried to put that value, which is an array, into a var, but it is an array in an array, somehow. What I used was:

`$queried_imagemeta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );
print_r($queried_imagemeta);`

Comment: Oops, waited to long. So, I use:

`$queried_imagemeta = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'gallery_data', $gallery_data );
print_r($queried_imagemeta);`

That outputs:

`Array ([0] => Array 99[image_url] => Array ([0] => http://image-url-1.jpg [1] http://image-url-2.jpg )))`

and what I need is the value, the actual url's of both those images...