# how to show posts with different background for every post in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show different posts on my page but the problem is that every post has a unique background image which is, at the moment, added via background image property.
I need to replace this with WordPress, but I don't now how to achieve that. The idea I have is to use post thumbnail image as a background image, but in the post there is also a thumbnail showing up in the content.

It's the scenario of the post, background image, then comes the title, description and then comes the thumbnail.  Sorry I could not upload any screen shot of my work, but I am trying my best to describe the whole scenario. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an excellent time to use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).  Once you have it installed, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new field group.
2. Add a new field of type "image".
3. Make the rules for post-type is equal to post.

Now in your template file, you can fetch the image like this:

```
<?php
  // Where 'image' is the name of the field you added
  $image = get_field('image');
?>
```

Then you can include the image wherever you like later in the same template file, for example:

```
<div class="hentry" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>)"></div>
```

And in your CSS, assuming you want the background image to take up the whole background of the post:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hentry  {
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
  }
</style>
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer brother, but the issue is that my client wants nothing like above stuff. He is just interested in custom coding and nothing else :( ..... so, i have to find that solution only according to his scenario ... by the way really thanks for your help and time ... stay happy.

Comment: No problem.  I have added a second answer that could be more useful to you.  There is no third-party plugin required for that one.  Let me know if it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe my first answer will still be helpful to some, but since you cannot use Advanced Custom Fields or another plugin, you could add the following code in your `functions.php` file instead.

Note that I have taken and slightly modified the code from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452453/2263949) to limit it to one image instead of a group of images, and I have made use of the more modern media uploader.

Also, this will only add the custom field to your `post` type, and not your pages, custom post types, etc.  Look through the code, and I'm sure your can figure out how to change that if so desired.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_post_image_so_30337102' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'print_scripts_so_30337102' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'print_scripts_so_30337102' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_post_image_so_30337102', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add custom Meta Box to Posts post type
 */
function add_post_image_so_30337102() 
{
    wp_enqueue_media();
    add_meta_box(
        'post_image',
        'Custom Uploader',
        'post_image_options_so_30337102',
        'post',
        'normal',
        'core'
    );
}

/**
 * Print the Meta Box content
 */
function post_image_options_so_30337102()
{
    global $post;
    $image_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_data', true );

    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'noncename_so_30337102' );
?>

<div id="dynamic_form">

    <div id="field_wrap">
        <div class="field_row">

          <div class="field_left">
            <div class="form_field">
              <label>Image URL</label>
              <input type="text"
                     class="meta_image_url"
                     name="image[image_url]"
                     value="<?php esc_html_e( isset($image_data['image_url']) ? $image_data['image_url'] : '' ); ?>"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="form_field">
              <label>Description</label>
              <input type="text"
                     class="meta_image_desc"
                     name="image[image_desc]"
                     value="<?php esc_html_e( isset($image_data['image_desc']) ? $image_data['image_desc'] : '' ); ?>"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="field_right image_wrap">
            <img src="<?php esc_html_e( $image_data['image_url'] ); ?>" height="48" width="48" />
          </div>

          <div class="field_right">
            <input class="button" type="button" value="Choose File" onclick="add_image(this)" /><br />
          </div>

          <div class="clear" /></div> 
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

  <?php
}

/**
 * Print styles and scripts
 */
function print_scripts_so_30337102()
{
    // Check for correct post_type
    global $post;
    if( 'post' != $post->post_type )
        return;
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
      .field_left {
        float:left;
      }

      .field_right {
        float:left;
        margin-left:10px;
      }

      .clear {
        clear:both;
      }

      #dynamic_form {
        width:580px;
      }

      #dynamic_form input[type=text] {
        width:300px;
      }

      #dynamic_form .field_row {
        border:1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        padding:10px;
      }

      #dynamic_form label {
        padding:0 6px;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- New script taken from here: http://brinidesigner.com/use-wordpress-3-5-new-media-uploader-for-your-plugin-and-theme-options-panel-development/ -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add_image(obj) {
            var parent=jQuery(obj).parent().parent('div.field_row');
            var inputField = jQuery(parent).find("input.meta_image_url");

            var image = wp.media({ 
                title: 'Upload Image',
                // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                multiple: false
            }).open()
            .on('select', function(e){
                // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
                var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
                // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
                // Output to the console uploaded_image
                //console.log(uploaded_image);
                var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
                // Let's assign the url value to the input field
                inputField.val(image_url);
                jQuery(parent)
                .find("div.image_wrap")
                .html('<img src="'+image_url+'" height="48" width="48" />');
            });

            return false;  
        }

    </script>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Save post action, process fields
 */
function update_post_image_so_30337102( $post_id, $post_object )
{
    // Doing revision, exit earlier **can be removed**
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;

    // Doing revision, exit earlier
    if ( 'revision' == $post_object->post_type )
        return;

    // Verify authenticity
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_so_30337102'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // Correct post type
    if ( 'post' != $_POST['post_type'] )
        return;

    if ( $_POST['image'] )
    {
        // Build array for saving post meta
        $image_data = array();
        if ( '' != $_POST['image']['image_url'] )
        {
            $image_data['image_url']  = $_POST['image']['image_url'];
            $image_data['image_desc'] = $_POST['image']['image_desc'];
        }

        if ( $image_data )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'image_data', $image_data );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'image_data' );
    }
    // Nothing received, all fields are empty, delete option
    else
    {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'image_data' );
    }
}
```

Now you can get the image URL (and description) inside of your `the_post()` loop of your template like this:

```
$image_data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'image_data', true );
```

And then echo the image like this.  You can re-use the CSS from my first answer.

```
<div class="hentry" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image_data['image_url']; ?>)"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your such in detail answer, i'll really be using it ... and your top one answer definitely will add help to some one else ... :) thanks again ... would love to follow you as well

Comment: No problem.  :)  You can upvote answers you find useful by pressing the upwards arrow.  It's gives the person that answered a few pionts.