# Allow user to add any number of text fields on WordPress theme option page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my theme, there's a theme option page. I want my users to be able to add any number of texts fields as they want.

[image: This is basically how it should work]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    (function () {
        $('.dd').on('click', '.addRow', function () {
            var start = $('#fields'),
                newRow = $('<input type="text" class="quantity" /><br><br>');
            $(start).append(newRow);
        });
    })();
});
```

```html
<div class="dd">
    <div id="fields">
        <input type="text" class="quantity" /><br><br>
    </div>
    <p class="addRow">Add a Row</p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</div>
```

This is how I implemented it on just HTML and JS.

[Check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tharindulucky/p03zxqze/)

Now I want to store these data in the Wordpress DB. So, how this is going to work? How can I integrate PHP with these virtual text fields?

Thanks!

Comment: Just FYI - your HTML is invalid. Only `li` elements can be direct children of `ul`.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13676404/1287812) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14452453/1287812)